# Laravel Eloquent relationship Many to Many

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, one-to-many

A user can have one whitelabel.
A whitelabel can have many users.
I have a pivot table with `whitelabel_id`, and `user_id` columns
I have both relationships set up using `->belongsToMany()` (with the inverse).

I am using a pivot table because I don't have a whitelabel_id on the users table (and won't be putting one in) so its defined as a `many-to-many`, but really it's `one-to-many`. I just get the `first()` whitelabel as there'll only be one for each user.

With this in mind. How do I `select * users` with the currently authenticated user's whitelabel?

I have this, it works, but is this the "Laravel" way? I feel it's slightly over engineered and Laravel would have a shorthand method.

```
$user->when(auth()->user()->whitelabel->first(), function ($query) {
    return 
    $query->whereIn('id', auth()->user()->whitelabel->first()->users->pluck('id'));
})
```

This checks if the auth user has a whitelabel, and then gets all users with the same whitelabel.

**Does Laravel have a quick shorthand for this?**

Comment: If you've defined the inverse correctly, auth()->user()->whitelabel->first()->users should give you all of the users of that label. Does it not?

Comment: It does yes, but it only needs to do that `when` there's a whitelabel relation present. Which is why I put it in the $user->when() part. Maybe it really is just all I need and my solution is correct and this was a dumb question? It just feels super wrong to do it this way.

Comment: It does seem a little lengthy, but apart from adding a scope it's hard to tell what you can do about it. You can add ->first() to the end of your relationship method on the model since they will only ever have one to save some space.

Comment: Stems from not having a well normalised database structure. Apologies for the slightly vague, probably StackOverflow inappropriate question. 8-) Thanks for the straight up answer though.

Comment: Unable to return `first()` in a relation as it returns an Eloquent Object, and not a Relation. However I can do `->take(1)` which achieves the same thing. Slightly more optimal, however I still have to do `whitelabel->first()` because I am returned a collection still, (albeit with 1 item). Close enough though!

Answer (score 0):

Models:

```
class Whitelabel
{
    public function users()
    {
       return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
}
class User
{
    public function whitelabels()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Whitelabel::class);
    }
}
```

you can retrieve records for simple

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id())
$user->whitelabels
```

if you want return all user in Auth user's whitelabel

```
foreach($user->whitelabels as $whitelabel){
    $whitelabel->users
}
```